# Mock function without executing it using unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a function that loads data from a `data.json` file defined in `models.py` as follow:

```
def load_data():
    file_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'data.json'
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)['data']
        return data

loaded_data = load_data()
```

I used `loaded_data` throughout all fuctions defined in `models.py`. The `data.json` file contains a JSON array.

My `test_models.py` is as follow:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from models import ... (a list of function to test)


# For replaceing model.load_data()
mock_data = []
def get_mock_data():
    return mock_data


@patch('models.load_data', side_effect= get_mock_restaurants)
class TestRestaurantsModel(unittest.TestCase):
```

However, somehow the real `models.load_data` still get executed. I know it because I changed the `file_path` to `randomabc.json` and got `FileNotFoundError`. How to I prevent the execution of `models.load_data`? I do not need to mock `models.load_data` essentially. I just need to prevent its execution during the test and assigned a mock data to `models.data`.

Comment: Please provide the `load_data` function. Where do you define it? I didn't see you call `load_data` in a function.

Comment: I edited. Please check.